# Get Bounding Polygon from contour images

Tags: tensorflow, feature-extraction, bounding-box, opencv, python

I have a dataset of contour images.
In my dataset, each image contain SINGLE object (on black background) which corresponds to a contour-image (i.e. image corresponding to a particular detected contour earlier), retrieved earlier.
I just have these images, and no other contour information.
I need to get contour polygon (height, width, polygon coordinates) for each image so that I can use this dataset for training in Tensorflow models.

Will running cv2.findContours() make sense (as each image is already a single contour) or is there another faster way to extract the bounding polygon from the contour images ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: ....convexHull?

Comment: cv2.boundingRect ?